# clear/truncate file in C when already open in "r+" mode

Tags: c, fopen, truncate, c89

My code currently looks something like this (these steps splitted into multiple functions):

```
/* open file */
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r+");

if(!file) {

  /* read the file */

  /* modify the data */

  /* truncate file (how does this work?)*/

  /* write new data into file */

  /* close file */
  fclose(file);
}
```

I know I could open the file with in `"w"` mode, but I don't want to do this in this case. I know there is a function `ftruncate` in `unistd.h`/`sys/types.h`, but I don't want to use these functions my code should be highly portable (on windows too).

Is there a possibility to clear a file without closing/reopen it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With standard C, the only way is to reopen the file in "w+" mode every time you need to truncate. You can use `freopen()` for this. "w+" will continue to allow reading from it, so there's no need to close and reopen yet again in "r+" mode. The semantics of "w+" are:

> Open for reading and writing. The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

(Taken from the fopen(3) man page.)

You can pass a NULL pointer as the filename parameter when using `freopen()`:

```
my_file = freopen(NULL, "w+", my_file);
```

If you don't need to read from the file anymore at all, when "w" mode will also do just fine.

Comment: OP wants a platform independent solution and does not want to re-open the file. And still use r+. :)

Comment: @askmish Which isn't possible :-P

Comment: @Nkos: Its possible, but, the optimal solution would be really complex(involving kernel calls, using buffered mechanisms, etc.), which given OP's question seems overkill. :(

Comment: @askmish Using kernel calls would make it non-portable. Just like using POSIX or w32 APIs. The only way to do this is with platform-specific code. Portable code (meaning pure ANSI C) cannot do this.

Comment: Agreed with what you just said.

Comment: This helped me, I didn't knew you didn't have to close the file. I now used `rewind(file); fopen(filename, "w");`. And i can still use the file pointer `file`! Would be nice if you could embed this into your answer.

Comment: @Mogria I've updated the answer. However, the correct way is to use `freopen()` instead of `fopen()`. If you simply use `fopen()` again, you leak the old FILE (analogous to allocating memory with `malloc()` but then not freeing it with `free()`.) It's easier too, since you don't need to pass a filename if you have an already open FILE handle.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function something like this:(pseudo code)

```
if(this is linux box) 
use truncate()
else if (this is windows box)
use _chsize_s()
```

This is the most straightforward solution for your requirement.

Refer: man truncate and _chsize_s at msdn.microsoft.com

and include necessary header files too.

Comment: I knew this would work, but I only do this if I really need to and there's no other way,.