# How to remove contents of the file when opened using r+ mode?

Tags: file, file-io, lua, file-manipulation

I've got my file open using `r+` mode. I've made some alteration to it, and I would like to remove the contents of it starting from X to the end of the file.

Unfortunately I have no clue how to do that. I've been browsing through the docs, but there's no mention of that.

I don't want to write `:space:` to the file so it "looks" like it's cleared, I would like to make it smaller as well.

Opening the file using `w` is not an option in this case.

Comment: Can you provide a real example? I'm afraid I didn't understand your question.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, `r+` opens the file for read and write.

Comment: Standart C did not provide such function. So as Lua. You can create new file an rewrite old one or use some external io  Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a file with `r+` mode preserves the current content; as the result, I don't think there is a way to truncate the rest of the file using the functions available in Lua. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981018/clear-truncate-file-in-c-when-already-open-in-r-mode) indicates that it can be done using `reopen` with `w+`, but since you indicated that you can't open it for writing, **I don't think there is a way to do what you want**.

Testing on this script produces `new contentext` (where `ext` is the leftover from the earlier content):

```
local f = io.open("somefile", "w")
f:write("some long text")
f:close()

local f = io.open("somefile", "r+")
f:write("new content")
f:close()
```

Comment: Probably a `seek` call to position?

Comment: You can do that, but it doesn't remove the existing content though, which is what OP wants to do.

Comment: Thank you Paul for providing an example. This is exactly the issue I'm having. `seek` only changes current position of the carret, but how do I remove data from there? I am fine with a loop which would do it, I just don't know what to write there.

Comment: @Krystian, I don't see a way to do it unfortunately, given your constraints.

Comment: You can try using [ljsyscall](https://github.com/justincormack/ljsyscall), which includes `truncate` and `ftruncate`, but it requires LuaJIT/FFI or Lua/luaffi.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, the only way I have found to truncate a file in **Lua** is to write the contents to a secondary file in `"w+"` mode, and then rename the secondary file to overwrite the original file. You will probably want to use this method sparingly depending on the size of the file, of course.

In this example `"path"` is the path to the original file

```
local file, err = io.open( path + ".tmp", "w+" )
if not file then return end

file:write( truncated_data )
file:close( )

assert( os.rename( path + ".tmp", path ) )
```