# How to read, truncate and write locked file, without unlocking?

Tags: c, linux, fopen, race-condition

Consider a file, that is edited with a frequency of tens, hundreds multiple processes per second. Since two or more processes can race for a file access for writing, there need a mechanism to be implemented, to make only one process to access file at one time.

As I understand, calling `fopen` (or `open`), until the `fclose` will do the job - these functions guarantee, that only one process will access the file.

The problem is that the file is needed to be truncated **after** being opened, because there is a need to read it first and after that rewrite. If there will be two `fopen` calls, obviously it will not guarantee cross-process safety.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981644/23306950) recommends to use `freopen` function after `fopen` and before `fclose` calls, however, according to the Linux man-pages, [`freopen` documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3p.html):

> If pathname is not a null pointer, freopen() shall close any file descriptor associated with stream.

Currently, the only solution I see is to create an associated file, with the needed to be accessed, and lock it, instead of locking the needed file (although it also be locked for sure), for the period, needed file will be read, closed, truncated, wrote, closed.

Is at least such solution will guarantee safety? Any better solutions?

---

As users in comments explained me, `fopen` does not prevent a file from being opened in another process at all. Instead, `flock` should be called additionally.

So the question is can I lock the file, read, truncate, write and then unlock it, or I should use solution with associated file, I described above?

---

**Specific summary question**

1. As I understand, `flock` accepts file descriptor need to be locked as an argument (and exactly descriptor from `open`, not `fopen`).
2. But, as I understand, read, truncation and write file requires opening, closing and again opening the file.
3. So, according to second fact, if I lock the file before I call `close`, will it be locked after `close` call? If it automatically unlocks due to `close` it does not make any sense. If it is not unlocks, how to unlock it after all manipulations?

Comment: *As I understand, calling `fopen` (or `open`), until the `fclose` will do the job - these functions guarantee, that only one process will access the file.*   Umm, **no**.  Where did you learn that?

Comment: Is this XY question? Are you asking how to protect two processes from writing to the same file at the same time __or__ you are specifically asking if it is "safe" (please define safeness) to truncate a file? If this is really _high_ frequency, I would consider rather writing a deamon that listens to a socket and then asynchronously flushes the messages to the disc using some mmap. How much is high frequency? 1GB per second? What operating system are you using? The behavior of which flags in freopen looks to be implementation defined , freopen may not truncate at all.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, well I think long ago, when studied c. At least, currently, I just made two same programs that try to `fopen` waiting some time after it, and outputing, if `fopen` returned `NULL`. So I ran one program instance, it successfully open the file, and then run another instance and it outputed, that `fopen` returned `NULL`. What do You mean by "no"? You mean cases with high frequencies?

Comment: `What do You mean by "no"?` No, means there is no guarantee that between fopen and fclose other processes will open or write or even remove the file. Such guarantee is completely unrelated and sounds surprising. fopen (and open) exist so you can open concurrently the same file from multiple processes. Mentioning `open` function suggests you are using Linux.

Comment: @KamilCuk, and was not asking about how to protect two process from writing to the same file at the same time, since I understood how to do that, but as AndrewHenle states, probably I understand it wrong. As safeness - I need solution that guarentees, that read file, that will be wrote, right after read is actualized, during writing, because if I read file, getting it contents to somehow change it to write such changed contents back, close it, and then again open, considering recently obtained contents is actualized to write, there can be a chance, that between close and open it was changed.

Comment: @KamilCuk, added Linux tag. So I need to search the internet how to indeed make file be prevented to read/write from another process, and it will also answer the question about truncation of already opened file? Update: seems `flock` is the answer, but it uses file descriptor from `open`, that in my case need to be closed and opened back.

Comment: The lockfile and the file that the lockfile represents a lock on don't need to be the same file. You can have `data` and `data.lck`, and as long as nothing edits `data` without having an exclusive lock on `data.lck` (or reads `data` without having a shared lock on `data.lck`) you're fine.

Comment: @KamilCuk, `How much is high frequency?` - tens, hundreeds of processes, trying to access the file per second

Comment: If you've got that level of concurrency, it might be a place where you want to have a file format defined for range locking, as opposed to flock's descriptor-level locking; the range-lock approach means that a process can have exclusive access to only _a specific region within_ a file.

Comment: What is the point of the file in the first place if it's ok to lose everything written in it by truncating it at arbitrary times?  Would it perhaps be better to simply open and write to the null device?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yeah, this is what I was writing about as a possible solution, calling it associated file. So the only clarification, is that I also need to "lock" the associated file?

Comment: (What John says, btw -- for any file where contents are critical, where performance constraints permit you should update it by writing to a new file, flushing that file, and renaming it over the original after the write and flush are fully successful; where performance constraints _don't_ permit then you get things like journaling)

Comment: Tens or hundreds of processes accessing the file per second?  And all of them are updating it?  How many are writing all-new content?  How many are just reading it?  FWIW, if you **update** the data, you can never really guarantee that readers will get valid data.

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv, right, as long as everything that modifies your "real" file follows the convention, then using an "associated file" as your lockfile is fine. That said, you still risk data loss when your program crashes (or your computer loses power) between the truncate and the following write/flush unless you either do journaling or follow the create-and-rename approach.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, ...ensuring consistency during read is why one has the readers grab a shared lock.

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv, ...if you want journaling, range locking, and all the other tricky stuff done "for free" instead of needing to implement it yourself -- use a proper database library. While this is heavier concurrency than SQLite is usually advised for, it's unlikely anything you homebrew will be able to do any better.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, each proccess always rewrite the file. But the file is small (less than kilobyte)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And that will likely starve writers if there are a significant number of readers, and how will writers handle being locked out?  If they wait in a queue, how will there be any assurance that the most up-to-date writer will go last?  Maybe the writer that was blocked for 10 minutes goes last?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, right, that's why I've given the OP advice about other tools (range locking vs file-level locking; proper database libraries; etc). I'd rather guide someone to an approach that may not scale as they need but will avoid corrupting their data than guide them into data loss.

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv *each proccess always rewrite the file* Who is reading the file?  If no process reads the data, there's no point to writing it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, ...that said, it sounds like the OP's file is small enough that they may not have such great difficulties as long as the write transactions are all either short or reorderable (to allow a fail-and-retry approach if anything else changed the file while heavy-lifting approaches took place)

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv, ...anyhow, the file being small makes the create-and-rename approach all the more reasonable; you do that, and anything that grabs a read handle doesn't need to worry about the data in the inode the handle is attached to being changed behind it, because new updates will all happen in new inodes that replace the one the directory entry points to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Then just write a new file each time and use `rename()` to replace the one that's being read.

Comment: Yes, I've advised the OP in that direction thrice now -- first time was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77891488/is-it-safe-to-use-freopen-with-existing-stream-to-truncate-already-open-file#comment137318507_77891488)

Comment: `tens, hundreeds of processes, trying to access the file per second` This is a file, so it is a I/O operation, so I am asking about throughput, in bytes read/written by second. If that is so, do you want to write to hard drive that much? What are you really implementing? Are you implementing shared memory between processes that you want to have access from multiple processes? Shared memory exists, and is shared, and is in memory. Why is it a file? What is the purpose of the file? If this is for communication, have you considered other interprocess communication methods?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, as I wrote in the orginal post - each process each time (every 1 second) reads the file, truncate it rewrite. There is no diffrence in the order of which process will rewrite file first, which last, the only key, is that the changes, that was made by one process should not be lost by rewriting to file by another process, that read the file **before** previous process changed it. It should be strictly `P1read-P1truncate-P1write -> P2read-P2truncate-P2write`, not `P1read-P2read-P1truncate-P1write-P2truncate-P2write`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, well I do not think it is important. Each process is an instance of a parser. They all store data to the different files. But there is one file, that just contains information of how many items each parser has stored, consider just an array string, and each process (instance of parser) update value to the specific array position.

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv, if your file has a separate section per parser, then there are much better ways to do this. Put each section in a different page of the file (aligning them at 4k boundaries) and have each parser overwrite _only its section_ in place. You could even use `mmap` here and make the updates look like memory access without explicit file I/O at all.

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv, ...that'll mean a larger file, but it'll mean that each parser only rewrites _its own_ section, and you never have two parsers squabbling over the same disk blocks.

Comment: (though I wonder why you try to have a single unified file at all, vs a separate file per subprocess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write,

> Consider a file, that is edited with a frequency of tens, hundreds multiple processes per second. Since two or more processes can race for a file access for writing, there need a mechanism to be implemented, to make only one process to access file at one time.

and you clarify that

> It should be strictly `P1read-P1truncate-P1write -> P2read-P2truncate-P2write`, not `P1read-P2read-P1truncate-P1write-P2truncate-P2write`

That is, you want to *serialize* units of read(+truncate)+write access to the file.

> As I understand, calling `fopen` (or `open`), until the `fclose` will do the job - these functions guarantee, that only one process will access the file.

Absolutely not.  Neither C nor POSIX makes any such guarantee. In practice, it is not typically true on POSIX systems, and it is not true on Linux in particular.  You might see such behavior on Windows, however, which could be where you got the idea.

**If you must use a physical file** for this purpose then you will need to perform some sort of locking around access to it.  Provided that the file is on a local filesystem, the most natural locking mechanism would be `flock()`.  This implements an advisory locking system, meaning that it applies only to processes that explicitly gate their access via `flock()`, but that does not appear to be an issue for your planned use.  `flock()` has the advantage that if a process dies while holding the lock (with the result that the underlying open file description is closed) then the lock is automatically released.  `flock()` has the disadvantage that it will not work if the file is replaced -- only if processes always modify it in place.

Another alternative would be a process-shared mutex or semaphore or a named semaphore, which the processes would use (again, cooperatively) to ensure the needed serialization.  This has the advantage that it could still work if the file is altogether replaced instead of modified in-place, but the possible disadvantage that if one of the participating processes dies while holding the mutex / semaphore locked then the whole system gets jammed.  (But if you use System V semaphores instead of POSIX semaphores then that shortcoming can be addressed.)

**But what if you *don't* use a physical file?** What you're describing sounds like it will require moderately high I/O bandwidth, and it will do a great deal of rewriting the same sectors of the underlying physical medium.  Why do you want to hit a disk so hard?  Or to deal with slow file I/O? You probably would be better off using shared memory (still protected by mutex or semaphore). Or you could implement a data broker service that runs on the system and mediates access to the data.

#### Addendum - response to additional questions about `flock`

> 1. As I understand, `flock` accepts file descriptor need to be locked as an argument (and exactly descriptor from `open`, not `fopen`).

Sort of.  `flock()` requires a file descriptor (from `open`) to identify the file to lock.  The *file* is locked, not the file descriptor, but that lock is associated with the file descriptor.

And if you want to use `stdio` functions to read and write the file, then you can get a `FILE *` from the file descriptor via `fdopen()`.  The file descriptor is still underneath, so that will not interfere with the locking.  If you do this, however, then you should be sure to close via `fclose()`ing the stream from `fdopen`, not directly `close()`ing the file descriptor underneath.

> 2. But, as I understand, read, truncation and write file requires opening, closing and again opening the file.

That is incorrect.

If the data to be written are the same length then you don't need to explicitly truncate at all.  After reading the file, `rewind()`ing to the beginning or `fseek()`ing or `lseek()`ing there, then writing, then closing will have the desired effect.

If the data to be written might be shorter then you can `truncate()` the file to any length (including 0) without first closing it.

> 3. So, according to second fact, if I lock the file before I call close, will it be locked after close call?

No, and it doesn't need to be (see above). Moreover, it is a convenience that you just need to close the file, not explicitly unlock it.

**Outline**

```
  // ...

  // open the file for reading and writing, creating it if necessary
  int fd = open(path_to_file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);

  // acquire an exclusive lock on the file, blocking if necessary
  int result = flock(fd, LOCK_EX);

  // Wrap the file descriptor in a stream
  FILE *file = fdopen(fd, "r+");

  // ... read the file ...

  // Rewind to the beginning
  rewind(file);

  // Truncate if necessary:
  result = truncate(fd, 0);

  // ... write new data ...

  // close the file and underlying file descriptor, flushing any
  // buffered output to it.  The lock is hereby released.
  result = fclose(file);

  // done
```

Note that for clarity and simplicity, I have omitted testing for or handling errors from the various functions.  Production code does not have that luxury.

Comment: Can You please add details, for the physical file case? I also updated my original post

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv, I updated this answer with additional details.

Comment: If rewind without truncation and write data, that length is smaller, than the current, then it will save last part of the initial data. For example, currently file content is `abcdef`, I write to it string `ghk` with `r+` mode, and the content will be `ghkdef`. Obviously, I would not create this post, if `r+` could write "truncationally".

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv, if you cannot rely on the new content to be at least the same length then you can still `truncate()` the file without first closing it.  I have updated this answer to address that.

Comment: But you would still be better off *not* relying on a regular file.

Answer (score 0):

I will ignore everything about `freopen` and `fopen`, as I suspect they are unrelated to your problem. If you are interested *specifically only* about `freopen` behavior, which might be a fun topic, consider asking a separate question.

No, `fopen` give no guarantee about any concurency. You can `fopen` and `open` files in parallel as many times as you want.

> Each process is an instance of a parser. They all store data to the different files. But there is one file, that just contains information of how many items each parser has stored, consider just an array string, and each process (instance of parser) update value to the specific array position

Great. The simplest to achieve data consistency is to use locking. There is no file locking in standard C, so use operating system mechnisis - in this case Linux or POSIX.

I would do: should the parser write or read from the file, first it `flock`s the file, make the modifications or reads from it, and then un`flock`s it for other processes to use. Read `man 2 flock`, and there is also `man 3 flock` command line utility. Each process may have pre-`open()`-ed the file to protect against `rename` or `unlink` or to reduce overhead.

Comment: Can I read, truncate and write the locked file, without unlocking it?

Comment: You can read, truncate, remove, write to any file, irrelevant if it is `flock`ed or not. Locking has no effect on operations of the file. Locking has effect on locking. If a file is `flock`ed, and another process tries to `flock` it, it will fail. You can still read, truncate, remove and write to a `flock`ed file. If you are searching for locking done on the file system level, that's generally a bad idea. In such case just use an interface which will force to use a locking mechanisms, - i.e. implement a function on top of `flock`, or just use a database, even sqlite.